# Stopping fscanf?

Tags: c, fopen, scanf

I'm writing a grade book program for school and I'm confused about one thing. We have a file to read from that has multiple student IDs and multiple scores. Would doing this:

```
results = fscanf(gradebook, "%d %d %d %d", id, sco1, sco2, sco3);
```

store the number into those variables as it reads then stop the cursor when it runs out of variables to store the information in?...then should I jump right into a calculation function to calculate the final grade before having it loop the fscanf for the next student?

```
results = fscanf(gradebook, "%d %d %d %d", id, sco1, sco2, sco3);
          getCalc(sco1, sco2, sco3);
```

Is that allowed? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What types are `id`, `sco1`, `sco2`, and `sco3`? Pointers? Are they initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a working example giving the average grade for every student id:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int     id, sco1, sco2, sco3;

        while (fscanf(stdin, "%d%d%d%d", &id, &sco1, &sco2, &sco3) == 4)
        {
                printf("%d: %g\n", id, (sco1+sco2+(double)sco3)/3.0);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would doing this:
>
> results = fscanf(gradebook, "%d %d %d %d", id, sco1,
> sco2, sco3);
>
> store the number into those variables as it reads then
> stop the cursor when it runs out of variables to store the information
> in?

No, unless it is in a while loop, it stops exactly after reading the four entries ONCE, unless you are using the value from `results` to control a while loop and call fscanf() multiple times to scan 4 entries at every call.

Example:-

```
//Keeps reading unless it encounters less than 4 parameters, which might be the case
//if an end of file is reached, or your data pattern changes.

while(  fscanf(gradebook, "%d %d %d %d", id, sco1, sco2, sco3) == 4 )
{
 //You can pass the data of individual id, to calculate function, and compute the required
 //sum, total or other data locally in the function, there is really no reason to use pass
 //address in your case, so just transfer data using pass by value method. 
 getCalc(id,sco1,sco2,sco3);   
}
```

Comment: The condition should be `while(fscanf(...) == 4)`, you mistyped.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your first and second questions: The type of `id`, `sco1`, `sco2` and `sco3` should be `int *` (that is, a **pointer** to an `int`), these variables should explicitly point to actual `int` objects and you should check the return value (`results`) before you use them. For example:

```
int a, b, c, d;
int *id = &a, *sco1 = &b, *sco2 = &c, *sco3 = &d;
int results = fscanf(gradebook, "%d %d %d %d", id, sco1, sco2, sco3);
if (results == 4) {
    getCalc(sco1, sco2, sco3);
}
```

Furthermore, getCalc should accept arguments of the type `int *`. With all of these requirements fulfilled, the answer to your third question is: Yes, you can call `getCalc` with `sco1`, `sco2` and `sco3` as arguments.

As you have probably guessed, the intermediate pointer variables are unnecessary here, and this can be simplified. However, this simplification requires a modification to your `fscanf` expression (the insertion of `&addressof` operators):

```
int id, sco1, sco2, sco3;
int results = fscanf(gradebook, "%d %d %d %d", &id, &sco1, &sco2, &sco3);
if (results == 4) {
    getCalc(&sco1, &sco2, &sco3);
}
```

Which book are you reading?